# How do you search and replace multiple lines in KDE Kate?

Tags: search, replace, kate

how do you replace multiple lines of code in Kate?

The following is the original text:

```
<div id="image">
<br style="clear: left"/>
<br style="clear: left"/>
<br style="clear: left"/>
<!-- Begin logo -->
...
<!-- End logo -->
</div>
```

This is the text that I would like to have:

```
<div id="image">
<!-- Begin logo -->
...
<!-- End logo -->
</div>
```

Comment: `kate`'s search and replace only works on a single line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> you switch into the search & replace mode. In the bar on the bottom, you first have to select as `Mode` either `Escape sequences` or `Regular expressions`.

For instance, if you choose `Escape sequences`, click the right mouse button on the search field. A context menu appears with an item called `Add`, listing some valid escape sequences, among which you will find `\n`. The same apples for the replace line edit. The context menu is also available in the `Regular expressions` mode.

Comment: Just to clarify: an explicit \n is necessary even when other constructs might ordinarily match line breaks:
  <font[^>]*>(([^<]|\n)*)</font>
and
  <font[^>]*>([^<]*)</font>
behave differently: the former will match across line breaks and the latter does not.

Answer (score 0):

Using `\n` to represent a newline works in `gedit` and most other editors I've tried, it should work in Kate too, does it?

Even selecting 2 lines and "dragging" them, or copy the 2 lines together and paste into gedit's search box copied the text with the `\n` in the correct spot.

[Kate's webpage](http://kate-editor.org/about-kate/) advertises "support for multiline search & replace"